Как исполнить команду при запуске системы в Linux?
Привет! Есть команда xkbcomp /etc/myxkbmap $DISPLAY как можно сделать так что бы при запуске системы эта команда автоматически выполнилась, а если возможно то можно ли запустить эту команду где-то в grub что бы при вводе пароля для входа в систему эта команда была уже выполнена. Я пытался засунуть команду в bash-скрипт вот так:
xkbcomp /etc/myxkbmap $DISPLAY

Но когда я через bash-скрипт запускаю эта команда не работает поэтому мне приходится ее запускать через терминал вводя команду xkbcomp /etc/myxkbmap $DISPLAY.
Warning: No symbols defined for <JPCM> (keycode 103)
Warning: No symbols defined for <I120> (keycode 120)
Warning: No symbols defined for <AE13> (keycode 132)
Warning: No symbols defined for <I149> (keycode 149)
Warning: No symbols defined for <I154> (keycode 154)
Warning: No symbols defined for <I168> (keycode 168)
Warning: No symbols defined for <I178> (keycode 178)
Warning: No symbols defined for <I183> (keycode 183)
Warning: No symbols defined for <I184> (keycode 184)
Warning: No symbols defined for <FK19> (keycode 197)
Warning: No symbols defined for <FK24> (keycode 202)
Warning: No symbols defined for <I217> (keycode 217)
Warning: No symbols defined for <I219> (keycode 219)
Warning: No symbols defined for <I222> (keycode 222)
Warning: No symbols defined for <I230> (keycode 230)
Warning: No symbols defined for <I248> (keycode 248)

Хоть мне пишут предупреждения, но команда работает!
Так вот есть ли способ запустить команду xkbcomp /etc/myxkbmap $DISPLAY при старте системы ?

DISPLAY это переменная X сервера.
~/.xinitrc удобен для запуска программ, зависящих от X, и установки переменных окружения при запуске X-сервера. Если он присутствует в домашнем каталоге пользователя, startx и xinit выполнят его. Иначе startx выполнит по умолчанию /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.
Если используете дисплейный менеджер, то нужен файл xprofile, ~/.xprofile и /etc/xprofile, позволяют выполнять команды при старте сессии, то есть до старта оконного менеджера.
Не знаю дает ли ваша команда эффект в wayland, но если не получится с xprofile - попробуйте xdg autostart.
xprofile по стилю похож на xinitrc.
Скорее всего так
nano $HOME/.xprofile

файл
xkbcomp /etc/myxkbmap $DISPLAY &


Спасибо за ответ! А можно по подробнее, у меня в корневом каталоге нету ~/.xinitrc  и так же нет файла xprofile

в домашнем. создай. и этот файл будет скрытый

я создал файл .xinitrc в /home, далее засунул туда команду xkbcomp /etc/myxkbmap $DISPLAY . Дал права на выполнение sudo chmod +x .xinitrc, но видимо я что-то неправильно сделал т.к после перезагрузки системы. Моя команда не выполнилась!

в /home ? надо в домашней папке пользователя

надо .xprofile если используется дисплейный менеджер

я создал в домашней директории файл .xprofile и засунул туда команду xkbcomp /etc/myxkbmap $DISPLAY Но при перезагрузке эта команд не выполнилась.
Но вот я создал bash-скрипт и теперь нужно его запускать при запуске системы как это можно сделать?

Странно. Дм какой у вас?

Простите я новичок, что такое Дм ? И что такое дисплейный менеджер?

@Может все таки bash-скрипт просто в автозагрузку засунуть ?
